# How do you access a URL in an array and send a user to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array:

```
   var sortedArray = [
    [string, url]
    [string, url]
    [string, url]
    [string, url]
   ];
```

I have a variable that is set from user input. That variable gets matched to the string in the array by looping through it, and I want to be able to send the person to the URL contained in the proper nested array. From my loop below, I can see that the loop is matching the string to the right index, but then how do I access the right nested array index to obtain the URL to use in a window.location.href = event?

```
    for (var i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
        var stuff = sortedArray[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < stuff.length; j++) {
            if(stuff.indexOf(jobSelect) !== -1) {
                console.log("match");
                break;

                } 
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Approach: Filter the array and then return the url**

```
var sortedArray = [
    ["test", "testurl"],
    ["teststring2", "testurl2"]
   ];

// grab the array that you want

const jobArray = (jobSelect) => {
  return sortedArray.filter(val => {
    return val[0] === jobSelect
  }
}

// jobArray('teststring2') returns an array of length 1 containing the array of 2 elements you need
```

From here, you can access the url by calling:

```
const userURL = jobArray[0][1]

// returns 'testurl2'
```

Answer (score 0):

in your second for statement you iterating through the inner array. No need to do that, when the inner array has always the same structure.

```
var job = stuff[0];
var url = stuff[1];
```